# In $\triangle PQR$ with $QR^2+PR^2=5PQ^2$, medians $PM$ and $QN$ meet at $G$. Find $\angle QGM$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, angle

This problem becomes much simpler if we solve it using coordinate geometry but i am seeking a solution which involves pure geometry.

> Consider a $\triangle PQR$ in which the relation
> $$QR^2+PR^2=5PQ^2$$
> holds. Let $G$ be the point of intersection of medians $PM$ and $QN$. Then find the value of $\angle QGM$.

Comment: Pls add a diagram and show us what you have tried.

Comment: Please include your coordinate-based proof. It may help someone devise a "pure" proof without duplicating the effort. Besides, showing your own work helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. (An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort tends to make a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$QR^2+PR^2=5PQ^2$

[median lengths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_(geometry)#Formulas_involving_the_medians%27_lengths)

$$PM=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2(PQ^2+PR^2)-QR^2}$$
$$PM=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2\left(\frac{x^2+y^2}{5}+y^2\right)-x^2}=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{12 y^2}{5}-\frac{3 x^2}{5}}$$
$$QN=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2\left(\frac{x^2+y^2}{5}+x^2\right)-y^2}=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{12 x^2}{5}-\frac{3 y^2}{5}}$$

$$GM=\frac{1}{3}PM=\frac{1}{6} \sqrt{\frac{12 y^2}{5}-\frac{3 x^2}{5}}$$
$$GQ=\frac{2}{3}QN=\frac{1}{3} \sqrt{\frac{12 x^2}{5}-\frac{3 y^2}{5}}$$
$$GM^2+GQ^2=\frac{x^2}{4}=QM^2\to \widehat{QGM}=90°$$

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

From the [triangle median theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonius%27s_theorem)
$$NQ^2= \frac12( RQ^2+ PQ^2)-\frac14RP^2, \>\>\>
MP^2= \frac12( RP^2+ PQ^2)-\frac14 RQ^2
$$
Combine the two equalities
$$NQ^2 +MP^2 = PQ^2 +\frac14(RQ^2+RP^2)= \frac94 PQ^2$$

Then, substitute it into the cosine rule below
\begin{align}
\cos\angle MGN= \frac{NG^2+MG^2- NM^2}{2NG\cdot MG}= \frac{\frac19 (NQ^2+MP^2)- \frac14 PQ^2}{2NG\cdot MG}=0
\end{align}Thus, $\angle QGM = \angle MGN =90^\circ$.